# Swift Vapor index.html is not recognised by server as default

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift

Hi I am using vapor for server side with swift programming language. For file serving I correctly configured the middleware in xcode. But `index.html` in the folder is not recognisable by server itself. But calling specific file `http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html` works fine.

If I call `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` only then there is an error

> "open(file:oFlag:mode:): No such file or directory (errno: 2)"

**Code:**

```
import Vapor

import FluentSQL
import FluentKit
import FluentMySQLDriver

// configures your application
public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
     app.middleware.use(FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: app.directory.publicDirectory))
    app.views.use(.plaintext)
    try routes(app)
}
```

In the `routes(_ app: Application)` I used to serve html file by below method but this is also not working and got same error.

```
app.get("folder") { req in
     
    req.view.render("index.html")
}
```

How can I serve html file programmatically also How can I make the server `index.html` recognisable when calling `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing up what is served using the file middleware and via a route. Your route `http://127.0.01:8080/folder` is looking for a file called `index.html` in `Resources/Views` - that's why you are getting the error at the moment. `http://localhost:8080/index.html` works because you have a file named `index.html` in `Public`.

I suggest moving `index.html` into `Resources/Views` and controlling access via routes. Use `Public` for static content, JS, etc. not your actual webpages.

I use the following method to define my routes. This can be in `configure.swift`, but for larger apps I tend to put it in a helper function, with the other registrations, in a separate file.

```swift
try app.register(collection: InsecureController())
```

The controller is defined as:

```swift
struct InsecureController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) {
        routes.get("", use: index)
        routes.get("index.html", use: index)
    }

    func index(request: Request) async throws -> View {
        return try await request.view.render("index.html")
    }
}
```

This results in your app responding to both `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/index.html`.

Answer (score 2):

Vapor [4.54.0](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/releases/tag/4.54.0) added support for default files in `FileMiddleware`. This allows you to put the `index.html` in `Public/folder` and it will serve `index.html` when a request to `/folder` is made etc etc

In configure.swift change your `FileMiddleware` to:

```swift
// Serves `index.html` (if it exists) to a request to `http://server.com/`, as well as any subdirectories
app.middleware.use(FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: "public/", defaultFile: "index.html"))
```